# Plugin wpmudev chat doesn't work when a function is called

Tags: php, ajax

In a a custom post php file (single-xxx) there is function and a plugin called

```
$post_id = functionX();
...
echo do_shortcode([chat id='5']);
```

When at the end of the `functionX`, there is `die;` the chat is not displayed (no matter it is called before or after `$post_id`...).

What can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

It is ok.
In the php file header there was `acf_form();`
Not using it, there is no issue.